# Some problems with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

(sorry for my English ;)

I started to use CanCan from rbates, this is awesome gem, but I have some problems:
I have Scrap model and there is boolean field :published (so, it means published/not published (draft)).

I have this rule in my ability.rb:

```
can :create, [Scrap]
can [:update, :destroy], [Scrap] do |object|
  object.try(:user) == user
end
```

So, this object cant be edited/updated/deleted by non-author. I want to do the same with my "show" action (non-author cant read drafts, really? ;) What is the true way to do this?

Thanx all!
Andrey Ognevsky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
can :show, Scrap do |scrap|
  scrap.published || scrap.user == user
end
```

Comment: :read means :index and :show, so users will not be able to view :index action;)

i tried to write smth like this:

can :read, :all do |object_class, object|
  object_class != "Scrap"
end
can :index, Scrap
can :show, Scrap do |scrap|
  scrap.published || scrap.user == user
end

but i think here is too many code for one small action ;/ I believe there is more simple way for doing this.

Comment: sure, it becomes the same i wrote in my comment (here is no line breaks for comments...), but i think it's too many text for one small action ;(

Comment: I don't think that's too many code.. You're telling cancan exactly what you want: Users can only see a scrap if the scrap is published or if the scrap owner is the current logged in user =)